# How to get tab order of wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, ui-automation

I am working on some UI automation for verify tab order of our WPF application. I was wondering if there was a Windows API or UIA API for getting the current tab order of the application under test. My UI automation is written in C# but I am more then willing to do some pinvokes to make this work.

Here is some clarification based off of @CodyGray's comment. My company's has certain tab orders that we want to rarely change if ever because our users are so used to these tab orders as part of their workflow (they operate the user interface faster than it can update via these tab orders...). The current way I am doing this is through keeping a list of the tab orders then using [SendKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx) to tab and check which control has focus. I then double check if the focused control is the control I expect it to be from a hard coded list. I would prefer to actually ask the application what it's tab order is going to be instead of using [SendKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx) which could send tabs to the incorrect window based on what has focus.

Comment: `GetNextDlgTabItem` might be an option. The tab order is just the Z order of the child controls, so iterating through the control windows works, too. Your question is quite underspecified to my taste. What exactly are you trying to do? What does it mean to "verify" the tab order? How can that be done programmatically? And what does it have to do with UI Automation?

Comment: @CodyGray I added some more context for you. Thank you for the response.